# What is the name of grammar that change noun to verb by adding (します)?

Tags: grammar

I would like to know the **name/Google keyword** of the grammar point (to search for further reading on Google).

When you add します to a noun, it become a verb.

仕事 = work (noun) 
仕事 します= I work

Comment: Suru-verbs, probably.

Answer (score 1):

It's [名詞]{めいし}の[動詞化]{どうしか} as a noun phrase or [名詞]{めいし}を[動詞化]{どうしか}する in a verb form.

This might be of your help: https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/3942450.html